# How to fix sum_array function in assembly 32bit

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

i try to sum an array in assembly with the help of stack but results ain't acceptable.

i tried to debug the code by printing results of ecx register at that moment. i also tried using gdb to debug but i don't know how i can print the stack pointed out by esp or ebp

```
.extern printf
.extern exit
.extern scanf
.extern read

hex:    .asciz  "%x"
hexn:   .asciz  "%x\n"
intn:   .asciz  "%d\n"
strn:       .asciz  "%s\n"
charn:  .asciz  "%c"

pr_int:
    pushal
    pushl   %eax
    push    $intn
    call    printf
    addl    $8, %esp
    popal
    ret

pr_str:
    pushal
    pushl   %esi
    call    printf
    addl    $4, %esp
    popal
    ret

pr_hex:
    pushal
    pushl   %eax
    push    $hexn
    call    printf
    addl    $8, %esp
    popal
    ret

pr_char:
    pushal
    pushl   %eax
    push    $charn
    call    printf
    addl    $8, %esp
    popal
    ret

read_hex:
    pushl    %ebp
    movl     %esp, %ebp
    sub     $4, %esp
    # Keep important registers.
    # We can't use pusha here, because the result is inside eax.
    pushl    %ebx
    pushl    %ecx
    pushl    %edx

    leal     -4(,%ebp), %ebp
    pushl    %ebx
    push     $hex
    call    scanf
    addl    $8, %esp
    mov     (,%ebx),    %eax

    # Restore registers:
    popl     %edx
    popl     %ecx
    popl     %ebx
    leave
    ret
```

```
.include    "include.s"

.section    .text

.align  32
.globl     main

main:
    pushl   $arr
    pushl   $arrlen
    call    sum
    addl    $8, %esp
    call    pr_int
    ret

sum:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    xor %edx, %edx
    xor %ecx, %ecx
    movl    20(,%ebp), %ecx

# debugging code
movl    %ecx,   %eax
call    pr_int
xor %eax, %eax
# debugging code ends

    movl    24(,%ebp), %eax
sum_arr:

    addl    (,%eax), %edx
    addl    $4, %eax
    dec %ecx
    loopne  sum_arr
    popl    %ebp
    ret

arr:    .long   1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
arrlen = (. - arr)/4
```

I expect the output of sum function to be 45, but the actual output is some random number.

Comment: A literally random number that's different every time you run it?  Of not, what number.  [mcve].  In GDB you can use `x` to examine memory.  Use `help x` for info on format.

Comment: yeah a random negative number everytime i run the program

Comment: Could it be an address?  Did you link this as a PIE executable that randomizes addresses every time it runs (except in GDB)?  Anyway, you probably want `dec %ecx` / `jnz`, not `loopne`.  `loopne` *also* decrements ECX before checking it for non-zero.  Don't use `loop` or `loopcc` (except for advanced optimization for code-size at the expense of speed).

Comment: yes sir i can say that it adds an address to it thats why a negative number in decimal. thanks for gdb help. now i can print contents pointed out by esp register